# Can't connect to database with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.6

I have started learn Symfony. After reading the documentation of Symfony I wanted to try make my application. I have already created a mysql database with the some data, but I can't connect to it within doctrine. As i read in the documentation, if i want to import my database into orm, i have to execute this commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import TestBundle yml

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities TestBundle
```

But i got message

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]
>     Attempted to call function "mysqli_init" from namespace "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli".

I successfully use mysqli in my flat-php application, but can't use in doctrine. Also the data for database connection is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use slightly different configuration:

```
// app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
... // another configuration here
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
```

and set your database driver to **pdo_mysql**:

```
// src/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
```

Comment: Did it. Got this messages:
`[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]              
  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver`
                                   
`[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]  
  could not find driver`        
`[PDOException]         
  could not find driver`
But in phpinfo() i have support of PDO.

Comment: @JohnDoe Then i could recommend you to reinstall virtual server. Maybe you'll find easier to use xampp